# InvalidTemplate error when using nested "reference()" calls

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am attempting to get a private link's private IP address within an ARM template as part of deploying a private link endpoint and it's corresponding private DNS entry. I'm able to find the correct resource id for the NIC that's associated with the private endpoint, however when I attempt to pass that id directly into a call to `reference()` it fails with an `InvalidTemplate` error.

Here's a template that demonstrates the issue:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "privateEndpointName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "nic": {
            "type": "object",
            "value": "[reference(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints',parameters('privateEndpointName')), '2019-09-01').networkInterfaces[0].id, '2019-07-01')]"
        }
    },
    "functions": []
}
```

This fails with:

`The template output 'nic' at line '14' and column '16' is not valid: The template function 'reference' is not expected at this location. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using nested `reference()` calls will not work.

Although it's not listed in the docs, my own experience is that `reference` tries to instantly resolve itself when it's used in a template.

What this means is that when you use `reference(reference(resourceId()...)...)`, the template thinks you're trying to pass `reference` a `resourceId` of `reference(resourceId(...)...)`, which is obviously invalid. It's expecting it to start with `/subscriptions/`, not `reference`.

I'm sure you've already tested it, but try using the result of your nested `reference` (the `resourceId` of the NIC) directly in your template  to verify that it is indeed the nested `reference` and not your NIC's `resourceId` that is causing the problem.

Comment: Directly passing the NIC's `resourceId` does indeed work. I am attempting to use the IP address of the assigned NIC in the same template the private link endpoint is created so I won't have that information available. I'll update the question with that information.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this to work by using nested templates in a collector pattern.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/building-blocks/extending-templates/collector

In this model, you will probably want two nested template deployments:

1. The first template will perform a reference on the private endpoint and set it as an output.
2. The second template will take a parameter for the private endpoint and then perform the second reference and set it as an output.
3. In the parent template, you can then access the output of the second nested template.

You can achieve it with one, but the template becomes a little harder to read. Here is a rough sample on how to do it. You may need to fix some bits, but the general idea should remain the same. The ("[[" tells the template to resolve the template function in the context of the second (nested) template, all "[" will be resolved in the context of the first template).

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "privateEndpointName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
            "name": "privateEndpointDeployment",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "parameters": {
                    "nicId": { "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints',parameters('privateEndpointName')), '2019-09-01').networkInterfaces[0].id]" }
                },
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                        "nicId": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [],
                    "outputs": {
                        "nic": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "value": "[[reference(parameters('nicId'), '2019-07-01')]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "nic": {
            "type": "object",
            "value": "[reference('privateEndpointDeployment', '2015-01-01').outputs.nic.value]"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Definitely should be added in the Microsoft documentation